# python saving .pyw to desktop after running a program

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
from test2_new import *
```

When I run this, python is saving a `.pyw` file of `test2_new` to the deskop. Why is this happening and how do i fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the extension is `.pyw`, not `.pyc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pyw file is a windows specific format that is generated for GUi scripts. It causes windows to open the script directly in a window instead of launching a console. Most likely you are calling your script from the user desktop location. Try changing directories to your script location. Also if you are double click launching your py then it could also be defaulting to the desktop. Move that pyw to your script location and run that pyw directly.